# Docker MACVLAN only works Outbound

Tags: linux, docker, raspberry-pi3, macvlan, raspbian-buster

I'm trying to setup a MACVLAN for my docker containers.
I have a fresh Raspbian and Docker installation and followed the steps outlined to the Docker Documentation to create a MACVLAN: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-macvlan.

The Network looks as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "pub_net",
        "Id": "782c49f79f549b11f04a6df98b8b2cbf52deef072e036306231309e44a1c9f3a",
        "Created": "2020-02-25T14:44:12.105402396+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "macvlan",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.178.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.178.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "682a47a60a5478d19b8c6fc923e11c949f70c5c07fe4dc8d94a772524c2820a1": {
                "Name": "IoBroker",
                "EndpointID": "5e7068dd9330792a91e1f1f023bd052d91d1fa93f50a2eb670ef8be81b61587f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:b2:02",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.178.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "parent": "eth0"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
```

Let's say i have an Alpine container attached to that network. From inside the container, I can access the internet and everything on my network just fine. I can't however access any container inside the MACVLAN from outside. I know this does usually not work from the host, but I'm not trying to access the container from the host, but from another machine on my network. The IP of the Container is not reachable form the outside.

If I follow the steps to allow the host to access the containers on the MACVLAN (create another MACVLAN and add routing table entry), I can access the containers from the host, but still not from the outside.

Maybe this is more of a Linux networking issue than a Docker one?

Docker Version: 19.03.6
OS: Raspbian Buster 10, Kernel Version  4.19.97-v7+

Does ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like this is an ARP issue in the Linux Kernel version used in Raspbian. After Updating the Kernel via sudo rpi-update it now works for me.

Comment: I was wondering around for a week and and changed my macvlan config many times and tried different things but at last this fu**ing command solved the problem.
thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

actually I have the same issue since Friday last week.

If I ping the host trying to access the docker container, from the inside of the container (your alpine container), I can access the container from the outside, till I restart the container itself.

I know this is not a solution but maybe helps to identify the issue.

Best
Aviation

Comment: Right, that actually helps and I can reach the container from the outside. But it's not really a practical solution. Did anyone figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have a small workaround for your problem because I have the same issues.

I did a clean install of omv 5, after I did a

```
sudo rpi-update 20354bebcc2a8448128f2348e19e155910d25122
```

the string (hash) after the "rpi-update" command is the latest 4.19.118 Kernel that fix the ARP issues

I will wait to update to the 5.X Kernal after the issues of docker installation get solved.